# How to increase video memory in Wine? (Wine version 1.6.2)

Tags: graphics, wine, ram

I'm trying to run a program(BeamNG.drive) on Wine 1.6.2, and there seems to be a problem.

See, here's the thing: I can actually get it to load most of the way. But just before it would have finished loading the stuff I need, it just crashes.

It essentially says something along the lines of: "D3DERR_OUTOFVIDEOMEMORY , out of video memory, failed to allocate dynamic VB.". Right around that.

From what I've read, it sounds like I need to increase the video memory, but how exactly do I do that?

I did manage to find this:

http://wiki.winehq.org/UsefulRegistryKeys

But it doesn't seem to be terribly clear on how to actually fix certain problems. For example, I don't have a DirectX folder in my HKEY registry, anywhere. So what do I do now?

Comment: How much VRAM do you have, what GPU do you hgave. if you install direct x does it help ? You can use wine tricks app or just download from Microsoft.

Comment: Hello, Mark.   It seems to be a 256MB video card if I'm not mistaken:~$ lspci -v -s 00:01.0
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Richland [Radeon HD 8550G] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 1984
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 48
 Memory at e0000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
 I/O ports at 4000 [size=256]
 Memory at f0300000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
 Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
 Capabilities: <access denied>
 Kernel driver in use: radeon

Answer (score 10):

You can set the video memory size as your graphics card supports with winetricks like this:

```
winetricks videomemorysize=2048
```

2048 is the video memory size in MB.

You may need to install [`winetricks`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/winetricks/):

```
sudo apt-get install winetricks
```

Comment: I think you can find the memory available by looking at the output of `lspci -v` (or `lspci -v | grep -i VGA -A 10`)

Comment: With bigger amounts of ram than 2048 this fails with `Unknown arg videomemorysize=4096`

Answer (score 0):

256mb, no wonder you ran out of VRAM, thats nothing, you are trying to ru a REAL TIME PHISICS SIMULATION  you have no chance, please review the minimum specs

> ```
> Minimum spec
> ```
>
> CPU: Dual-core processor RAM:  4GB GPU: Something better than
>   integrated graphics (at least 512MB Video RAM) Windows 7/8 (32bit or
>   64bit)
>
> ```
>   Recommended spec
> ```
>
> CPU: Dual-core processor (Intel) or Quad-core processor (AMD) RAM: 4GB
>   DDR3 GPU: GTX 560, Radeon HD 7790 or equivalent and above (>1GB Video
>   RAM) Windows 7/8 (32bit or 64bit)
>
> ```
>    High end sys req.
> ```
>
> CPU: recent Quad-core processor (Intel) or recent Eight-core processor
>   (AMD) RAM: 8GB DDR3 GPU: GTX 670 or Radeon HD 7950 or better (>1GB
>   Video RAM) Windows 7/8 (32bit or 64bit)

I know the minimum says 512mb, but realisticly you need a modern (no more than two years old) 1GB dedicated video card.

See something like a GTX650, to get good performance.

Comment: With the graphics card stuff, I think with intel integrated ones they can use system memory as well.