# Increase dedicated video memory on Intel HD graphics

Tags: intel-graphics, ram, elementary

I was going to try and run EVE Online with PlayOnLinux on my Acer Aspire V3-371-79XR. The laptop has Intel HD Graphics 5500 inside, an i7 core and 8 GiB of DDR3 ram. I checked the dedicated video memory with lspci and found that by default, the amount of dedicated memory for video is 16M non-prefetchable and 256M prefetchable, which is a small amount considering the laptop having 8GiB of ram. I've googled a bit and it seems possible to increase that amount on windows but I haven't found any clue on how to do this on linux.

Any help would be much appreciated.

I am running Elementary OS Freya x64

Comment: I've answered your question it should be roughly the same answer across most modern Linux OSs - but please note Elementary OS is a 'unofficial' derivative and should be ([officially](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)) be asked [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or perhaps the Elementary OS forums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats a hardware thing. To actually increase it you would have upgrade the graphics hardware, most likely by adding a dedicated graphics card into a spare slot onto the motherboard (with the integrated intel ones, these are usually integrated into the motherboard or processor so to upgrade that you would need upgrade those).

Also note that the integrated graphics should be able to use more memory than it says in `lspci`, see [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/475405/178596) - basically check `sudo dmesg | grep drm`. This likely will be based on the system's RAM, and probably the same thing you thought Windowz could do. You should be fine according to the system requirements of the game even without this: [System Requirements - EVE Online Support](https://support.eveonline.com/hc/en-us/articles/202748741-System-Requirements)

If you are looking for how to set the video memory in Wine, try [this question](https://askubuntu.com/a/578430/178596). PlayOnLinux should include a option to allow you to set this when installing EVE online.

See also:

- [Wine AppDB entry](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=2249)
- [PlayOnLinux script](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-1630-EVE_online.html)

Comment: Yeah thanks. I've found the wine settings that set video memory.

Comment: Can you mention where the wine video memory setting